# Is it possible to run a Teradata query in Excel that uses Volatile tables?

Tags: teradata

My Teradata query creates a volatile that is used to join to existing views. When linking query to excel the following error pops up: "Teradata: [Teradata Database] [3932] Only an ET or null statement is legal after a DDL Statement". Is there a workaround for this for someone that does not have write permissions in teradata to create a real view or table? I want to avoid linking to Teradata in SQL and running an open query to pull in the data needed.

This is for Excel 2016 64bit and using Teradata version 15.10.1.12

Answer (score 0):

Normally this error will occur if you are using ANSI mode or have issued a BT (Begin Transaction) in BTET mode.

Here are a few workarounds to try:

1. Issue an `ET;` statement (commit) after the create volatile table statement. If you are using ANSI mode, use `COMMIT;` instead of `ET;`. If you are unsure, try each one in turn. Only one will be valid but both do the same thing. Make sure your Volatile table includes `ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS`
2. Try using BT ET mode (a.k.a. Teradata mode) when establishing the session. I do not remember where but there will be a setting in the ODBC configuration for this.
3. Try using a Global Temporary table. These work similarly to Volatile tables **except** you define them once and the definition sticks around. That is, you can create it in, say BTEQ, or SQL assistant etc. The definition is common to all users and sessions (i.e. your Excel session), but the content is transient and unique to each session (like a volatile table).
4. Move the select part of your insert into the volatile table into the query that selects the data from the volatile table. See simple example below.

If you do not have create Global Temporary table permissions, ask your DBA.

Here is a simple example to illustrate point 4.

Current:

```sql
create volatile table tmp (id Integer)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

insert into tmp
select customer_number
from customer
where X = Y and yr = 2019
;

select a,b,c
from another_tbl A join TMP T ON
    A.id = T.id
;
```

Becomes:

```sql
select a,b,c
from another_tbl A join (
        select customer_number
        from customer
        where X = Y and yr = 2019
        ) AS T
    ON
      A.id = T.id
;
```

Or better yet, just Join your tables directly.

**Note** The first sequence (create table, Insert into and select) is a three statement series. This will return 3 "result sets". The first two will be row counts the last will be the actual data. Most programs (including I think Excel) can not process multiple result set responses. This is one of the reasons it is difficult to use Teradata Macros with client tools like Excel.

The latter solution (a single select) avoids this potential problem.